# TD height of Table dosen't stretch to 100%

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table located here: http://www.friedmanllp.com/partnerdetailbiopage3.php?ContID=22

The TD of the gray box needs to lock up with the text of the right hand column bio. The outer surrounding TD stretches just not the inner.

Does anyone have any thoughts?

Please no lectures on using tables for site design, just trying to make this work.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not clicking on a random link from an unknown website. Could you provide more details, or replicate the problem on a http://jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 0):

The two columns share the same table and therefore the height of the columns must be the same, you have to split into two tables or even better use divs.

Answer (score 0):

Don't stick with the HTML4.0 specs, try using [HTML5 table's new features](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/table) as stated in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/table) page. 
Give that td or table a class/id and play with it by using all possible aligning methods like `margin`,`padding`,`text-align` `float` etc. Everything is so easy to tackle with it.

Comment: I can't re-doctype the site. Too big of an undertaking. I think I may not need the grey box to stretch after all though. So no worries.